# How can I fix the discrepancy between my code on Heroku and my code on Github?

Tags: git, heroku

My application code on Heroku is different from my application code on my computer and on Github. For the latest git commit I made, I added all of the revisions to my files using "git add ." and the correct changes I was looking for got pushed to Github, however when I pushed the code to Heroku several of the changes didn't take effect. The design of my web application on my local server has the correct attributes I'm looking for, however even after I committed the new application code to Heroku the design didn't change to reflect the changes in my code.

I'm not sure what could be causing this problem, or how I can go about fixing it. Any help you could give me would be great! Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you push to Heroku? Can you post the output?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. Some of the changes in my code take effect, but not all of them. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know that a lot of people will tell you the obvious.

git status

git commit -am "Your update message"

git push heroku master

heroku restart

However, I had this issue and the real problem was with the SSH key. 
I noticed that I was only able to make successful changes from a given machine. Delete the key for your machine on heroku and recreate and add the key again.

Are you using Windows or Linux?
Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm on a Mac. Let me try out your suggestion, and thanks for your help!